# How to select more than one number when I use them directly instead of "odd" and "even" on css?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make a layout on CSS getting help from a tutorial on CSS grid, the person on the video used the "even" and "odd" proprieties to select the numbers he was targeting to work on, but I wanted to choose the numbers myself so I could do things in a more personalized way(it only works with one number alone), but when I search here and other places all I get are things about columns, so I'm a little confused because I don't know if I am not searching with the proper words and terms of if there are no other proprieties to use and I end up thinking I'm not finding the answer when that may be the only answer, here's the code I saw on the tutorial which I wanted to modify:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />


        <title></title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <style>
    .grid div:nth-child(even){ 
     background-color:red;
    }
    .grid div:nth-child(3){ 
     background-color:green;
    }
    </style>

    <div class="grid">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

.grid div:nth-child(3){  <----This is the part I wanted to modify when I write the number alone(3), it selects the line I want correctly, but it doesn't work with more than 1 number(2,3,5), here lies my issue. I tried using , ; / but none of these works, it is probably something silly.

Comment: *or if there are no other propreties(typed if by accident)

Comment: You cant write more than one number in it. What is your choosing criteria for this

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple `nth-child` and separate them with a comma `,`.

```
.grid div:nth-child(2),
.grid div:nth-child(3),
.grid div:nth-child(5) {
  background-color:green;
}
```

Note: You can also use fomulas in your `nth-child` if you like, e.g. `nth-child(2n)`, `nth-child(4n+5)`, etc.

You can read more about the CSS `nth-child` property [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/).

Comment: That's what I'm talking about, thank you very much!!